# What word can I use when I need help to accomplish my task?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that I can use when that I need help to accomplish my task? For example, a situation where I want to learn another language and I am in need for native speakers of that language to help me.

Comment: Too broad. You **want** help or **need** help?

Comment: You could say you're ***dependent on** native speakers* in the matter of learning a foreign language. We'd probably need an exact context (a "fill in the blank word" sentence) to be more specific.

Comment: "Help!"  "Mayday!"  "SOS!"  "Somebody save me, please!"

Answer (score 0):

May it be a [necessity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/necessity) that you are asking for?

> something that is necessary :  requirement

Reference:
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/necessity

Answer (score 0):

**require**

[Merriam-Webster definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/require):

- to need (something)
- to make it necessary for someone to do something